# Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements

Tags: script

*This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)*

## [Searchbar & Nav Improvements](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#searchbar--nav-improvements)

- (Parent) Option to search child meta

  [image: screenshot]
- (Meta) New search bar on meta sites, and option to search parent site

  [image: screenshot]
- (Parent) Adds link to child meta in left sidebar

  [image: screenshot]
- (Meta) Adds link to parent in left sidebar

  [image: screenshot]
- **Advanced Search Helper when search box is focused**

  [image: screenshot]

  - Fill-in your watched/ignored tags!

    [image: screenshot]
  - Tag autocomplete

    [image: screenshot]
  - Username autocomplete

    [image: screenshot]
  - Useful add-ons!

    [image: screenshot]
- **Saved Searches**

  - Toggle from search results page

    [image: screenshot]
  - View list via toggle button in Advanced Search Helper

    [image: screenshot]
- **Auto Refresh**

  - Toggle from search results page

    [image: screenshot]
- **Instant Filter Toggles - Questions/Answers, Deleted/Not deleted**

  - Toggle from search results page

    [image: screenshot]

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LICENCE)

### Download

**[View source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js) ([Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js))**

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

### Code

This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

[Bug reports](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues), Forks, and PRs welcome!

Comment: This is my first post on Stack Apps, and feedback is very much appreciated. Feel free to report issues and suggest feature requests via the GitHub link above.

Comment: Good work! Looks very nice and solves some of my issues